# How do I parse JSON from a Java HTTPResponse?

Tags: java, android, json

I have an HttpResponse object for a web request I just made. The response is in the JSON format, so I need to parse it.  I can do it in an absurdly complex way, but it seems like there must be a better way.

Is this really the best I can do?

```
    HttpResponse response; // some response object
    Reader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
    char[] buf = new char[1000];
    int l = 0;
    while (l >= 0) {
        builder.append(buf, 0, l);
        l = in.read(buf);
    }
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener( builder.toString() );
    JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray( tokener );
```

I'm on Android if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Two things which can be done more efficiently:

1. Use [`StringBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of [`StringBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) since it's the faster and younger brother.
2. Use [`BufferedReader#readLine()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) to read it line by line instead of reading it char by char.

---

```
HttpResponse response; // some response object
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    builder.append(line).append("\n");
}
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(builder.toString());
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
```

If the JSON is actually a single line, then you can also remove the loop and builder.

```
HttpResponse response; // some response object
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String json = reader.readLine();
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
```

Comment: Won't the code in the question read it off the stream 1000 bytes at a time? Obviously it depends on the average line size of the output, but that could very well be fewer batches than one per line.

Comment: No, as the method name already hints, the `BufferedReader#readLine()` reads the stream line by line. I.e. it splits the stream on newlines. Give it a try and experience yourself.

Comment: Right. That's my point. If a line is less than 1000 characters on average using BufferedReader#readLine() will involve more times through the loop than BufferedReader#read(). (Not that the difference is likely to matter unless the output has a lot of short lines.)

Comment: The `BufferedReader` internally already buffers on 8KB. After all, this is likely microoptimization, either way is good enough, I would prefer more readable code above that. The idiom you're using is typical for byte streams, not for character streams. PS: why did you edit the question to replace the `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder`? Now my suggestion about that makes less sense for ones reading the question for first time :)

Comment: I just changed the variable name.  It was a StringBuilder in the original version of the question, but I can see where using the name "buffer" might have confused things. :)

Comment: Awesome.  Where is JSONTokener from?  I never can find these flippin' jar files.

Comment: Found JSONArray and JSONTokener jar [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.codeartisans%22%20AND%20a%3A%22org.json%22)

Answer (score 9):

Use JSON Simple,

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Which has a small foot-print, no dependencies so it's perfect for Android.

You can do something like this,

```
Object obj=JSONValue.parse(buffer.tString());
JSONArray finalResult=(JSONArray)obj;
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this over the built-in `org.json` package?

Comment: If you are familiar with org.json and your app is for Android only, it probably has no advantage. Otherwise, json-simple is much simpler to use and the JAR is much smaller (14k vs 43k). We use it everywhere, even on Android.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Gson library for parsing

```
void getJson() throws IOException {
    HttpClient  httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("some url of json");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MyClass myClassObj = gson.fromJson(response, MyClass.class);

}
```

here is sample json file which is fetchd from server

```
{
"id":5,
"name":"kitkat",
"version":"4.4"
}
```

here is my class

```
class MyClass{
int id;
String name;
String version;
}
```

refer [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) appears to support some amount of JSON parsing straight from an `InputStream`. My understanding is that it runs on Android and is fairly quick. On the other hand, it is an extra JAR to include with your app, increasing download and on-flash size.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
Reader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
char[] buf = new char[1000];
int l = 0;
while (l >= 0) {
    builder.append(buf, 0, l);
    l = in.read(buf);
}
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener( builder.toString() );
```

You can do:

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(
                           IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent()) );
```

where IOUtils is from the commons IO library.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, and using Apache's [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) Library for `IOUtils`:

```
// connection is a HttpURLConnection
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, baos);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(baos.toString()); // JSONObject is part of Android library
```

Answer (score -3):

There is no need to do the reader loop yourself. The JsonTokener has this built in. E.g.

```
ttpResponse response; // some response object
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new    
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(reader);
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
```

Comment: I can't find any constructor of JSONTokener which accepts a BufferedReader, therefore this answer is misleading.

Comment: There is no constructor which accepts a BufferedReader but a Reader and BufferedReader is a subclass of Reader.
--> org.json.JSONTokener(Reader reader)

Comment: This constructor doesn't seem be part of Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html

Comment: i got mine from from the json.org website which seems to be different to the android version.