# extract message body out of HttpResponse

Tags: android, json, httpresponse

Okay, I've successfully connected to a remote server and received a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response and the response is packed into the HttpResponse object. Now how do I get the data in the response out of it, specifically the JSON that was sent from the server?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

something like this: duplicate here : [How do I parse JSON from a Java HTTPResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845599/how-do-i-parse-json-from-a-java-httpresponse)

```
HttpResponse response; // some response object
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String json = reader.readLine();
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can get the body of the `HttpResponse` by calling `getEntity()` which returns an object of type `HttpEntity`.  You will then want to consume the `InputStream` that is returned from the `getContent()` method of the `HttpEntity`.  I would do it like this:

```
public static String entityToString(HttpEntity entity) {
  InputStream is = entity.getContent();
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

  String line = null;
  try {
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      str.append(line + "\n");
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } finally {
    try {
      is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      //tough luck...
    }
  }
  return str.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use EntityUtils

```
response = cl.execute(p); //cl is http client and p is the post request

if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
{
    try
    {
        String resp_body = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.v("resp_body", resp_body.toString());
        JSONObject jsobj = new JSONObject(resp_body);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

       Log.e("sometag",e.getMessage());
     }
}
```

PS : You may have to do this in a separate thread, other than the main thread, like in the doInBackground() of an AsyncTask or Network operation on main thread exception may occur.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BasicResponseHandler when calling httpclient.execute()

```
ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = httpclient.execute(httpget, resonseHandler);
```