# Decode json object to string android

Tags: java, android, json, decode

I used `json_encode();` to convert string to json in php and then response it to android but I can't use the response, how can I convert the json to string?
when I display the response it shows this :

"{\n'OK': \n[\n{\n'Name': 'MyName',\n'Gender':'Male'\n}\n]\n}"
what shall I do?

thank you

Comment: No need to append `\n` after every line when reading response from Stream

Comment: I don't append this is what I get from PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON from a Java HTTPResponse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845599/how-do-i-parse-json-from-a-java-httpresponse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just converting a string to json, you're not returning a JSONObject or JSONArray, according to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

If you must return a string, you may have to use some json library or write your own parser.

If that doesn't sound appealing, I recommending returning a JSONObject or JSONArray with one element.

For example:

**php**

```
echo json_encode( array('result' => 'the string you are encoding') );
```

**java**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject( encodedStringResponseFromPhp );
String theStringYouEncoded = (String) json.get( "result" );
```

You'll need to add a `throws JSONException` to the function you add this java code too or put it inside a try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a JSON-Library like https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/? Looks like you need some help [decoding the string](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** You should use the json2.js library from Douglas Crockford. It provides some extra features and better/older browser support.

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593046/jquery-json-to-string)

Comment: jquery? I'm talking about android ( java )