# How to parse Json data from HttpResponse

Tags: java, json

I want to parse `Json` response:

```
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Any suggestion how to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON from a Java HTTPResponse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845599/how-do-i-parse-json-from-a-java-httpresponse)

Answer (score 2):

You can use json-simple

https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

If you use maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in your code

```
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
    // get a String from the JSON object
    String firstName = (String) jsonObject.get("firstname");
    System.out.println("The first name is: " + firstName);
```

Here there is an example

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/java-json-parser-example/