# Using Apache Http Client for a POST request

Tags: java, json, gson, translators

I'm trying to develop a Java application with Gson to use an external api to get a simple text translation. Below is code and output. I've used my API key at the designated location for API key in the HTTP post URL
Could you please help me get this working?
Thank you very much.

// CODE

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("URL");

StringEntity input = new StringEntity(json);
input.setContentType("application/json");
post.setEntity(input);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
```

//OUTPUT

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, you received `404 Not Found` response from the server. Often it means that you send a request to wrong URL.

You should use https version of request as shown in [documentation](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/).
So the correct URL looks like this: `https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?lang=en-ru&key=API-KEY`.

**Edit**

Regarding the second issue, try to add header for your post.

```
post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

**Edit 2**

I looked into documentation, and they don't use body in request. Just add text to URL like this:

```
https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?text=live&lang=en-ru&key=API-KEY`
```

Don't forget to remove setting entity, I mean delete `post.setEntity(input)` and related stuff.

Comment: Thanks for reply.This is the URI I used with the API key

Comment: You mean you put there the correct API key, but this URL is just to show us an example?

Comment: Thank you. It worked!. But I receive a different error code now. :(

Comment: You should edit your question or create a new one, related that problem. Also show the `textConv`, it's hard to guess how it's represented.

Comment: Done!. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: textConv class is at the bottom

Comment: Tried adding the post.addheader(..). But same output. I think it's something wrong with my json conversion. Can't figure out what exactly :(

Comment: I tried adding the "text=live" part to URL, but same code 415.. If I'm to delete "input entity" how can I do the gson  conversion? Could you please explain a bit more. I'm a noob actually and trying understand this. Thanks so much

Comment: Oh I understand u're saying remove the input parameter and set the http post like this? post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));

Comment: I get this response {"text":"Text to be converted Hello World"}
[Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1,Content-Length: 43,Chunked: false]
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Your text to translate is in the URL, `text=live` is an example of translating the word "live". So remove `post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));` and related stuff, because you don't need the body in request.

Comment: oh right. Understood.One more thing. Could you please explain how I display the response? I have this code to print the response "System.out.println(response.getStatusLine()); System.out.println(response.getEntity());" and the respose printed is, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@117159c0 " Thank you

Comment: You've already asked for two things in one question. If you have another issue, ask a new question or search the Internet, because it's a common situation to handle JSON response (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845599/how-do-i-parse-json-from-a-java-httpresponse)). Furthermore if my solution resolved your problem, please accept the answer.